# C++ Method with an enum class type

Tags: c++, enums

A problem occurred when trying to print out a class method which has en enum class type.

**I have a method, which returns an enum which is casted to bool:**

```
bool Window::IsVSync() const
{
    return static_cast<bool>(m_WindowData.VSync);
}
```

`m_WindowData.VSync` is VSync type.

**And that's the enum class:**

```
enum class VSync : bool
{
    Disable = false,
    Enable = true
}
```

I know that with enum class I don't get an implicit conversion, and that's the reason I cast to bool. And like that everything is working just fine. But with the fact that my enum class is extended from bool in mind, **can I do something like this:**

```
VSync Window::IsVSync() const
{
    return m_WindowData.VSync;
}
```

At first, I thought I could, since we extend the enum class from bool, but I was wrong, and It **gives me this error when I try to print to the console:**

> binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
>   type 'VSync' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

**I print the method to the console with:**

```
std::cout << myWindow.IsVSync() << "\n";
```

Which is of course, supposed to return either 1 or 0;

When I cast it to bool in the output like that:

```
std::cout << static_cast<bool>(myWindow.IsVSync()) << "\n";
```

it works just fine, but I do not want to make the user have to cast it to bool for it to work. I need a solution which is in the method itself, so the calling stays like that

```
std::cout << myWindow.IsVSync() << "\n";
```

Comment: `return either 1 or 0;` - theere is no conversion from VSync to `'1'` or `'0'`. Write it. `std::cout << myWindow.IsVSync() == VSync::Disable ? '0' : '1'`.

Comment: Why should the user have to write this? I want to do it from the method
And it actually does work fine if I cast to bool when I output it, but again, I dont want to make the user do such a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a stream operator overload outside of the class for the enum type like so:

```
static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VSync& val)
{
    switch (val) {
        case VSync::Disable:
            os << "VSync disabled";
            break;
        case VSync::Enable:
            os << "VSync enabled";
            break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

In this way you don't need to cast anything and can print something more detailed than a `1` or `0` (or having to use `std::boolalpha`).

I hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly!
Where are operator overloadings usually put? I have a class, but you say it should be out of the class. Still it's connected with an enum which is in that class.

Comment: @JohnDavis since it's an `enum` class you can't have the operator overload directly in the enum declaration .. but you could put the operator overload in the class that the enum class is within ... personally, I usually put the stream operator overloads within the class they are meant for and mark the function as a friend so it can access private/protected members where need be.

Answer (score 1):

It is not extended from bool, is uses the same amount of space as a bool.
With enum, colon does not denote inheritance.